# How can I add the noise to the pores in this texture?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I have this texture that im trying to add pores to, Im using a voronoi texture to make the pores but they look too smooth, how would I go about mixing the noise into the pores so it blends better? Or perhaps theres a different method for adding pores like this? Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution was easier than I thought. Just another math node adding the voronoi and the noise together does the trick. I've also added another multiply node for more control over the voronoi.

[image]

[image]